# How to access a nested hash of arrays in a loop?

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I have data in this format

```
a1 1901 4
a1 1902 5
a3 1902 6
a4 1902 7
a4 1903 8
a5 1903 9
```

I want to calculate the cumulative score (3rd column) for each entity in the first column. So I tried to make a hash and my code looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file = shift;
open (DATA, $file);

my %hash;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($protein, $year, $score) = split /\s+/, $line;
  push @{ $hash{$protein}{$year} }, $score;
}

print Dumper \%hash;

close DATA:
```

The output looks like this

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a3' => {
                    '1902' => [
                                5
                              ]
                  },
          'a1' => {
                    '1902' => [
                                6
                              ],
                    '1901' => [
                                4
                              ]
                  },
          'a4' => {
                    '1903' => [
                                8
                              ],
                    '1902' => [
                                7
                              ]
                  },
          'a5' => {
                    '1903' => [
                                9
                              ]
                  }
        };
```

I now want to access each entity in column 1 (a1,a2,a3) and add the score, so the desired output will be something like this:

```
a1 1901 4
a1 1902 9    # 4+5
a3 1902 6
a4 1902 7
a4 1903 16   # 7+9
a5 1903 9
```

But I am unable to come up with how to access the values of the created hash in a loop in order to add the values?

Comment: Please dump a *reference to* the hash: `print Dumper \%hash`. The result is much more readable.

Comment: Do you want literally `score1+score2` or are  those fields in fact numeric and you want them totalled?

Comment: Thanks, Those are numeric and I want them totalled. I have edited the output of Dumper using \%hash. @Borodin

Comment: Thanks. The dump doesn't seem to correspond to the input. Why does `a1 1902` have `score1+score2`? Likewise, why does `a4 1903` have  `score4+score6`?

Comment: Don't use `DATA` as a file handle name; it's an existing handle. For that matter, don't use global vars like `DATA` in favour of lexical vars like `my $DATA`.

Comment: @Borodin, For a given protein, they want the score of the first year for the first year, the sum of the scores of the first two years for the second year, the sum of the scores of the first three years for the third year, etc.

Comment: Yeah, what i want is for a given protein then want the score of the first year for the first year, the combined score of the first two years for the second year, etc.@Borodin

Comment: @swati: This question has nothing to do with autovivication. I've removed it from the subject line and the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is always sorted as you show it then you can process the data as you read it from the file:

```perl
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($protein, $year, $score) = split;

    $total = 0 unless $protein eq $current;
    $total += $score;

    print "$protein $year $total\n";

    $current = $protein;
}
```

#### output

```
a1 1901 4
a1 1902 9
a3 1902 6
a4 1902 7
a4 1903 15
a5 1903 9
```

Comment: You mean sorted by entity in column 1 ??  Yes, it is.

Comment: @swati: It needs to be sorted by protein and by year within each protein.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
a4 1903 16   # Sum of a4 1902 and a5 1903
```

should be

```
a4 1903 15   # Sum of a4 1902 and a4 1903
```

If so,

```
my %scores_by_protein_and_year;
while (<DATA>) {
   my ($protein, $year, $score) = split;
   $scores_by_protein_and_year{$protein}{$year} = $score;
}

for my $protein (keys(%scores_by_protein_and_year)) {
   my $scores_by_year = $scores_by_protein_and_year{$protein};
   my $score = 0;
   for my $year (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%$scores_by_year)) {
      $score += $scores_by_year->{$year};
      say "$protein $year $score";
   }
}
```

This works even if the data isn't grouped/sorted.

Comment: Is it necessary to create two hash here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. 5 hashes are created for your sample data set, 1 + 1 per different protein. Unlike your data structure, however, mine doesn't include any arrays.

Comment: @swati: There's only one hash. There was a bug which I've fixed.